# Edit a comment - javascript, php working together

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, comments

Hey all, I am facing a rather serious security error. Let me first outline my code.

```
<li class="comment">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="edit-form" class="edit-area">
        <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 150px;"><?php echo $response->comment; ?></textarea>
    </form>

    <div class="comment-area" style="padding-top: 2px"><?php echo (parseResponse($response->comment)); ?></div>

        <p class="ranking">
            <?php if ($response->user_id == $user_id) : ?>
                    <a href="" class="editting" data-user="<?php echo md5(convert($response->user_id)); ?>" data-edit="<?php echo $response->short; ?>">Edit</a> &bull; <a href="#d">Delete</a> 
            <?php else : ?>
                <a href="#">Like (<?php echo $response->likes; ?>)</a> &bull; <a href="#">Dislike (<?php echo $response->dislikes; ?>)</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>                                        
</li>
```

is what I got in my body, and here's the relevant JS

```
$('.editting').bind('click', function(event) {
            var num = $(this).data('edit');
            var user = $(this).data('user');

            if ($(this).hasClass('done')) {

                var newComment = $('#comment-' + num + ' .edit-area textarea').val();
                var dataString = 'newComment='+ newComment + '&num=' + num;

                if(newComment == '')
                {
                    alert('Comment Cannot Be Empty!');
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "edit.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){}
                    });

                    $('#comment-' + num + ' .edit-area').slideDown('slow', function() {
                    $('#comment-' + num + ' .edit-area').addClass('invisible');
                    });     
                    $('#comment-' + num + ' .comment-area').slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $('#comment-' + num + ' .comment-area').removeClass('invisible');
                    });
                    $(this).removeClass('done');
                    $(this).html('Edit');
                }



            }

            else {                  
                $('#comment-' + num + ' .comment-area').slideDown('slow', function() {
                    $('#comment-' + num + ' .comment-area').addClass('invisible');
                });

                $('#comment-' + num + ' .edit-area').slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $('#comment-' + num + ' .edit-area').removeClass('invisible');
                });

                $(this).html('Done');
                $(this).addClass('done');


            }

            return false;


        });
```

which works fine, but i'm having an issue. If the user finds a comment (not by them) and uses a plugin like firebug, they can replace the response->short with another, and edit ANY comment. Of course, within edit.php, I could check the short against the response table and see if the user checks out, but i'd like to find a way to not show the text area unless that response is for-sure by that user.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Sure...but it'll do nothing to stop the user/fix your security hole.  To fix this **check server-side**, *always* double-check anything that should be secure server-side, never trust your input.  The users *trying* to do something malicious won't be stopped by anything in JavaScript...sending data to your server that they shouldn't is *exactly* what they'll do first.

Comment: well, I plan to do the edit.php thing anyway so that I'm sure it's valid, but is there anyway I can fortify the js too/

Comment: @tap - There isn't much you an do that you're not already, JavaScript is **wide** open, that's just how it is...I can open an edit window for any comment on this page as well...but the *server* won't allow it, and that's what matters.  Take a step back here and look at what you're trying to do...you're trying to make the interface a bit better for the specific case of someone *trying* to manipulate your site, I wouldn't do any extra work for that, just secure it server-side where it counts, design the interface for the other 99.9% of users (and still be secure where it matters!)

Answer (score 0):

Like Nick said; never ever trust a JavaScript test!

It will/might work for "regular users", but when it comes down to avoiding hacks, you might as well ask the hacker to click a button to "prove" his input is valid!

Your validator script is running on someone else's computer, so he/she will be able to manipulate it (or even turn it of using NoScript etc. )